# Can we open a FileStream explicitly in c#?

Tags: c#, .net-core, file-io, filestream, system.io.file

I'm using.NET Core 3.1 project. I have two methods which accept FileStream as a parameter. Let's say something like this.

```
 void A(FileStream fs)
  {
   try
     {
       //DO SOME OPERATIONS
     } 
     
   catch (Exception ex)
     {
     //CODE FOR CATCH BLOCK
     }
   finally
     {fs.close()}
 }
```

Now there is another method let's say method B which has same structure like method A but does some different operations.

```
void B(FileStream fs)
 {
   //SAME STRUCTURE AS OF 
     METHOD 'A' BUT 
     DIFFERENTT OPERATION.
 }
```

Now when I try to call these method one after the another with only one FileStream created, the first method that gets called closes the stream and second one can't access it.

```
FileStream fs= 
File.open("path\for\file") 
ObjectName.A(fs);
ObjectName.B(fs);
```

I can't do the steps mentioned above with this design of methods. But also, closing the stream is necessary. How can I make the stream get opened explicitly in methods? Or is there any other way of designing those methods so that I can achieve calling them one after another with same FileStream?

Comment: What do you mean by "explicitly"? I'm not really understanding what you're trying to do or what the issue is.

Comment: @John by that I mean if there is a way to do something like FileStream.Open() like we close it explicitly using close method.

Comment: `FileStream fs = File.open("path\for\file")` does this. You just need it in your methods.

Comment: The issue here is, your method took ownership of a stream and closed it, that is unusual to say the least

Comment: Methode `A` should not close the `FileStream` in the first place. You should use a `using` where you create the FileStream to automaticlly dispose of it after it will not be used anylonger

Comment: Either pass the path and have each method do a `using( FileStream fs ...` or pass the file stream but do not close it inside any of the methods. In latter case the client needs to take care of closing the fs. I personally would expect that the fs needs to be closed at the same "level" it has been created. Any thing else would surpise clients which is really a bad idea.